# Wordpress website not showing image on safari browser on Catalina OS below v13.0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

The WordPress website is not showing images in the safari web browser below version 13.0. I'm trying everything but nothing works. Tried SSL Content fix plugins, deleting the cache, deleted the cloudflare cache, changed http to HTTPS mix, reduced the plug-in version and the wordpress version but still nothing. However, it is perfectly working on other OS like VENTURA, MONTEREY, BIGSUR etc. Firstly, I made this website using a web image format, but after clients requested I change the image format webp to jpeg & png, I ran into issues. Here are the all website links:

`webp Image webiste : cons.webhubs.in jpeg image webiste : sikhsaguru.com png Image webiste : dev2.webhubs.in`

Answer (score 1):

Upload the image file directly to your website's Media file gallery and see if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Many people face the same problem with the Safari web browser. According to me, it happened because the origin server was serving mixed content to Cloudflare. So, you should check the SSL certificate on the origin server (the server that hosts your WordPress install, not Cloudflare).

If you don’t fix the mixed content in your WordPress install, the problem will return every few days/weeks.

Also check your site on Why No Padlock, it will help you to get to know the problem on the Webpage of the website regarding SSL.